# Object Reference Exception adding parameters to second oracle connection..Connection Pooling Issue?

Tags: connection-pooling, odp.net

I have two concurrent connections which execute one after the other. I have tried them out separately and both seem to run perfectly.. But when they run together ( one after the other like example below ) , it throws an Object Reference error.. Is this a possible issue cos of connection pooling?

```cs
     OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection (ConnectionString1))

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("proc1", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.parameters.add("param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2 , 20 , ParameterDirection.Input);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        conn.close()

     OracleConnection conn2 = new OracleConnection (ConnectionString2))

        OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand("proc2", conn2);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //Exception raised in the next line
        cmd2.parameters.add("param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2 , 20 , ParameterDirection.Input);
        conn2.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        conn2.close();
```

Comment: Which provider is this?  ODP.net from oracle or the old microsoft built-in version?  Can you include the stack trace please?

Comment: This is ODP.net.. I dont think I ll be able to get the stack trace.. But I have vaguely identified the Issue.. I had forgotten to mention that this is in a Distributed Transactional Architecture. This appears to be an issue if MS DTC is not properly configured.. We have gone with a work around anyways..